# Repairing cracks in plasterboard ceiling - ok to tape over paint?

Tags: repair, drywall, plaster, crack

I have cracks all around the edges of the plasterboard sheets in the ceilings throughout the house.  The cracks are pretty wide - about 1mm.  The ceilings are plasterboard with a skim coat and emulsion over the top, and the scrim tape is hessian (1950s house).  I'm about to redecorate and want to sort the cracks out first.

It seems I need to tape (e.g. FibaTape) and use jointing compound.  My question is whether it is ok to tape and fill over the paintwork or whether I will need to sand the paint off first?

Comment: FWIW I had similar cracks in an old house.  IIRC I scraped off any loose paint, put fibratape over and then joint compound, then painted.  10 years later there's no cracks.  I _think_ the answer is going to largely be dependent on the specifics of paint adhesion on the wall, the cracks, etc.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Use fibafuse tape not mesh or paper.

Option1... the best way but more work:
If the cracks are bad the proper way to do this is to take an oscillating tool preferably with a grout removal blade and cut out the crack all the way down to the lath (this will make a bit of a mesS). Make sure all loose material is removed. Then fill the crack with Durabond 90 making sure the mud mixture is thick not soupy. Push that mud into the old lath board. After it’s dried you might need to apply a second coat. Make sure surrounding  area is clean. Apply fibafuse tape with all purpose mud. Now do finishing coats.

Option 2...
Scrape off any loose paint. Clean surrounding area. Embed fibafusefuse tape NOT MESH TAPE in all purpose mud. Now do finish coats.

Your probably going to get some bubbles In your mud since this is a painted surface. It’s just going to require sanding and skim coating to fix. All purpose mud is important when embedding the tape as it has glue in it.

Comment: this is plasterboard (aka drywall) not plaster and lath.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: In that case take utility knife and cut out crack. There has to be reason for it cracking. Probably bad taping job.  Fill in the cut out crack with some hot mud. Then go about taping. Some people would not cut out old crack but if you want long term success I would.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it will be a continuing issue try 1/4 inch drywall over it. Done.